# in C char foo[foo] is not allowed, but why? and how to use input as declaration for this [foo]

Tags: c, char, declare

I am new in C and I am used to zx basic and z80 asm. I want to use the value of an input to make a character array but

```
int   amount_of_dice_sides ;
printf("Give number of sides of dice:\n") ;
scanf("%d", &amount_of_dice_sides) ;
char  all[amount_of_dice_sides] ;
```

is not allowed yet

```
int   amount_of_dice_sides=6 ;
char  all[6] ;
```

works very fine.... how do i get that
char  all[amount_of_dice_sides] ;
working?
its a very primer question, very 'basic' but i seem not to find an answer that does NOT start with 'the difference between const char*foo '
which has nothing to do with setting a char with an integer but only as a real value instead of a variable.
i found these possible 'char foo' but none is what i waht to achieve
https://medium.com/@bartobri/untangling-complex-c-declarations-9b6a0cf88c96

EDIT
i use another compiler then gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
    {
int   amount_of_dice_sides ;
printf("Give number of sides of dice:\n") ;
scanf("%d", &amount_of_dice_sides) ;
char  all[amount_of_dice_sides] ;
return ;
    }
```

works fine but not with zcc.
so i have to look at another place, and i am realy still learning.
see ya , and thanks for a load off immidiate answers. chris

Comment: `char all[amount_of_dice_sides];` is defining a **variable length array** which is (now) an optional feature of C and is not supported by all compilers. An alternative is to allocate memory dynamically, eg. `char *all = malloc(amount_of_dice_sides * sizeof *all);`

Comment: there's no `char foo[foo]` in your code. `char all[amount_of_dice_sides]` is very different and is called VLA (variable length array) and is a new feature in C99. And it's not quite a good idea compared to dynamically allocating memory

Comment: Another way would be to define an array with the maximum number of dice sides allowed, such as `char all[20];` and restrict the input to `20`.

Comment: @phuclv char foo[foo] is recursive offcourse, thats not what i ment, so the title is not correct indeed.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when someone enters -1?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @phuclv *...a new feature in C99...*  It's old enough to vote, get drafted, and buy alcohol in every state in the US.  *And it's not quite a good idea compared to dynamically allocating memory* Only if you like paying the performance penalty of being single-threaded through allocating and freeing heap memory. `char vla[size]` is on the current thread's stack and doesn't require locking a singular resource to access it. "Oh, but you'll use too much and overflow your stack!" is no different from "You'll `malloc()` too much!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle probably you've never programmed for embedded systems. Some don't even have dynamic allocation. Most compilers for z80 are so old that no C99 support exists either

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it isn't working is that you are using a compiler and MCU from the Jurassic period. Variable-length arrays (VLA) were introduced in the C language in the year 1999. Z80 might be a nice platform to learn one flavour of assembler, but it's a horrible platform for learning C.

But regardless, you should never use VLA allocation nor heap allocation on low end microcontrollers, because they have very limited memory in general and stack memory in particular. (And heap allocation simply [doesn't make sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).)

For the same reasons, you shouldn't be using `stdio.h` either, it will kill a significant amount of all available memory. Instead you should use the raw UART driver or write one yourself - assuming the stdio.h functions go to a terminal on a PC. Start by finding the linker map file, study it and see how much memory these libs actually take, then you'll see for yourself why they aren't suitable.

Answer (score 0):

C only allows variable length stack arrays in certain situations. Specifically when you have a function, you can use a calculation based on a parameter to have a stack allocated array.

```
void func(int param){
    int array[param] // call it here
    // do some work with array as a scratch space
}   // when the final curly bracket is called, the array is destroyed
```

However, this technique can easily get you into trouble. If you don't specify the length of an array, and a user enters a really big number, then you get a *Stack Overflow*. On early C compilers and platforms (like the Intel-8051), this was painfully common, as well as calling too many nested functions.

The solution is to allocate your variable length arrays on the heap. Some platforms do allow allocation to the stack as well, but not all of them.

```
// In sumfunc we roll a number of dice, print, and return the sum
// Malloc allocates to the heap
int sumFunc_malloc(int num_dice){
    int * dice = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_dice); // our allocation
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_dice; i++){
        dice[i] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        printf("Dice %d rolled a %d", i, dice[i];
        sum += dice[i];
    }
    free(dice); // REQUIRED or memory will leak, and eventually program will fail
    return sum;
}

// In sumfunc we roll a number of dice, print, and return the sum
// Alloca is not supported by all platforms, but is on the stack
int sumFunc_alloca(int num_dice){
    int * dice = (int*)alloca(sizeof(int) * num_dice); // our allocation on the stack
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_dice; i++){
        dice[i] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        printf("Dice %d rolled a %d", i, dice[i];
        sum += dice[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

One final alternative, especially on devices like the 8051 is to have a scratchpad that you do large work in, and simply reusing it.

```
static char scratch[100];

int func(int param){
    // use scratch to hold lots of temporary values
}
```

Comment: On microcontrollers, the right solution is rather to allocate as much memory as is required statically. You can make simple memory pools using static memory instead of using heap allocation, for example.

Comment: OP didn't specify the platform. He said that he was previously used to programming on the Zilog. If he's on running C on a Zilog, then he definitely shouldn't be allocating memory. However, if he's on an Intel? Knowing about allocation is a requirement to become a better programmer.

Comment: I'm saying that your "scratch" example should be allocating as memory as is required, not using some strange general purpose buffer shared between multiple functions. That's exactly how you end up with dangerous tight coupling between every piece of non-related code in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The best comment was explaining the WHY part: that compiling will set memory at a permanent location and if i change that size later C will get in trouble with allocated variables.

Meanwhile i do indeed learn C on a dinosar called [z88dk](https://github.com/z88dk/z88dk). And it took some time befoe i was able to use it.  z88dk is in a slow rewrite from 'classic' to SDCC and others aswell.

this one works in zcc but with BUILD_SCC=1 while building z88dk itself (!!!) and using a special lib for zx spectrum:

```
 /* C source start */
 /* by chris born ad 2020 as homework for z88dk, farkle */
 /* zcc +zx -vn -startup=0 -clib=sdcc_iy dice_026.c -o dice026 -create-app */

  #include <arch/zx.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int dice(int aods)
          {
  char d ;
    /*srand (seedrandom); */
      d =+ rand()%aods ;
      return d;
           }
    
  int main()
   {

   int x  , amount_of_dice_sides , hand_of_dice ;
   char number , hand[256] ;

   zx_cls(PAPER_WHITE) ;

   printf("Give number of sides of dice:\n") ;
   scanf("%d", &amount_of_dice_sides) ;
 
   printf("how many dice do you want:\n") ;
   scanf("%d", &hand_of_dice) ;
   printf(" amount of dice %d ",hand_of_dice );
   if (hand_of_dice > 255) 
          {
          hand_of_dice = 255 ;
          printf(" is now %d", hand_of_dice) ;
          }
   printf("\n") ;

   scanf("press a key") ;

 /* char   hand[&hand_of_dice];     */ /* int is max 65536 gives a huge hand     filled with stones */

   printf("You threw: \n");

   for (x=1 ; x<=hand_of_dice ;x++) 
        {
        number=dice(amount_of_dice_sides);
        printf("stone %d : %d  \n",x , number);
        hand[x]=number;
        }
        printf("\n");
   return 0;
   }

   /* C source end */
```

so why do i got stuck here?
well its the only source i realy have!

Answer (score -1):

In this declaration,

```
int   amount_of_dice_sides ;
printf("Give number of sides of dice:\n") ;
scanf("%d", &amount_of_dice_sides) ;
char  all[amount_of_dice_sides] ;
```

all[amount_of_dice_sides] is a static array & it's size needs to known to compiler prior building the code.

What happens in your case is size of array is being read as input from user which happens after compilation

It's always recommended to explicitly mention the size of array to avoid memory issues in code later

Comment: After edit, it would appear that the array is local, in which case the reason why it doesn't work is the outdated compiler.

Comment: The array all is not static. It is on automatic storage (stack).